# Can I ask user to select my answer or up vote my answer?

Tags: support

I am editing an answer and came across this line "Vote up and choose answer if I helped :D". Is it acceptable to ask the user to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that is the best way to phrase it. A user shouldn't ask the OP to accept *their* answer, rather they select the answer that helped them the most. I would probably add a comment (rather than editing your answer) and phrase it more like:

> Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the
>   answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also
>   [How does accepting an answer
>   work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

This means that you prompt them to accept an answer without requesting that they select yours.